# USB trouble - 2.0 storage device often connects as 1.0

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I have been facing some problems with the USB ports for a while.

1. The problems happen mostly with the front USB ports, not as much the back ones.
2. Connecting a USB 2.0 storage device sometimes gives the warning that it is operating in USB 1.0, and to achieve optimum performance I should connect it to a USB 2.0 port.
3. Lately out of the two front USB ports, one has stopped detecting certain kind of devices like pen drives. However, it still seems to function with the Bluetooth dongle.

Reinstalling the driver from Gigaabyte's site didn't help. However I don't have much experience about connecting the motherboard. I'm wondering could it be some kind of hardware malfunction - like loose connection etc?

Also most of these problems happen with either a pendrive or an external hard disk. If it is a software fault, could it be related to only the storage devices?

OS is Windows XP Pro SP3.
Motherboard is Gigabyte GA-M61SME-S2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your front USB ports have problems - either have them fixed/replaced or do not use.

A friend of mine had the same problem and by continuing to use his front USB he managed to fry his power supply.

So be careful.

Comment: Wow... that's pretty scary. Would you think there is any chance to fix this without getting a new MB?

Comment: Only a repairman can give an opinion with any value. It might only be a bad contact, or it might be more than that. Best to avoid using glitching components.

Comment: the panels are often separate chunks of PCB that mounts to the case, then then wires back to a header on the motherboard.  if that's the case here you may be able to find or build a replacement -- it's probably a problem with the ports than with the motherboard.  you can also check the connection to the motherboard and make sure it's solidly connected, but it may be easier for a beginner to have it looked at by a professional.

Answer (score 0):

Often the front USBs on a motherboard are not the same as the one's integrated in the back of the motherboard.
I have an ASRock Z97 which has USB 3.0 on the back, but only 2.0 rated for the front. Check your motherboard documentation to be sure.