# Device is no longer USB 2.0?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, usb-2, usb-flash-drive

I have a 32 GB pen drive that I have turned into my PC repair kit.  I have formatted it to be a boot-able drive with multiple .iso's for different options.  Recently however whenever I plug in the flash drive, I get the error "*This device can perform faster on a USB 2.0... yada yada yada*"  Thing is, I know that the ports that I'm plugging this into is USB 2.0.  *Some* ports do work *sometimes*, and this issue happens on *multiple* computers, so I'm assuming that it's not anything faulty with the actual USB ports (like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/60697/usb-trouble-2-0-storage-device-often-connects-as-1-0) one).

Is the fact that my drive is a boot-able drive (formatted to FAT 32) the reason for problems in connection?

Does anybody know how to rectify this issue?

Comment: *Is the fact that my drive is a boot-able drive (formatted to FAT 32) the reason for problems in connection?* >> I don't think so.

Comment: @Sathya It appears that this issue is a common one then (searches on internet).  Do you have any ideas what the issue is? Drivers perhaps?

Comment: I would see if you can RMA this drive as it sounds somewhat defective to me...

Comment: I'd agree with @Brandon. Perhaps try re-installing the drivers first ?

Comment: @Sathya @Brandon Will do with drivers... RMA maybe a little difficult as it was my prize from SuperUser and not purchased by me :)

Comment: @KronoS I figured that'd be the pendrive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess we can start with troubleshooting the USB finger first.

First we can isolate the problem onto either (1) the USB finger or (2) the host that the thumb drives' plugged in.

You can try to plug it into some other computer to see if it works at USB 2.0 speeds. Disregard warnings and see file copying speeds. Speed > 1.5MByte/second indicate USB 2.0 speeds. (USB 1.1 is capped at 12Mbps which is 1.5MBps, in reality with overheads it is less than 1MBps.)

If the problem is isolated at the drive, I think the best thing you could do is to RMA the drive and perhaps ask our moderators (hint: they are commenting on your question :p) if there are ways to do it.

If the problem is lying on the host, I guess we could be of more help here. Uninstall and reinstall drivers of USB Enhanced Host Controller as suggested by @Sathya. and keep us updated...